# how to skip the key of a json if the value is not filled? Laravel Vue Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I want to skip some json key if the value of this key is not filled. Because if it's not filled, it returns my bad result.

Check out my code on the backend and front-end.

Backend Laravel:

```
public function searchFilterCar(Request $request, Car $car)
{
    if ($request->has('car_type')) {
        $car = $car->where('car_type', $request->input('car_type'))->with('images');
    }
    if ($request->has('mark')) {
        $car = $car->where('mark', $request->input('mark'))->with('images');
    }
    if ($request->has('model')) {
        $car = $car->where('model', $request->input('model'))->with('images');
    }
    if ($request->has('fuel')) {
        $car = $car->where('fuel', $request->input('fuel'))->with('images');
    }
    if ($request->has('circuit')) {
        $car = $car->where('circuit', $request->input('circuit'))->with('images');
    }

    return response()->json($car->get());
}
```

Frontend Vue:

```
  async searchCar(){
    this.loading = true;
    try {
      let response = await axios.post('car/filtersearch', {
        car_type: this.selectedCarType,
        mark: this.selectedCarObject.name,
        model: this.selectedModel,
        fuel: this.selectedFuel,
        circuit: this.selectedCircuit
      });
      console.log(response);
      this.cars = response.data;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  },
```

Look at my payload. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAehD.jpg
I do not know if the solution is on the front or on the back? At the moment, I think it's easiest if an empty value does not send an absolutely json with that key and values ​​than just skipping them.
Maybe the backend could be a correction but I think it's easier on the front? Help?

Comment: It is better to post error messages here as well instead of sharing a scrrenshot. For example, in my country imgur.com is forbidden and I can't see what is the error.

Comment: I do not have the error just returning my bad result. If I send json with empty some of the values, give me a bad result. Example 
{ car_type: "Car",
"Mark" : "Bmw"
"Model" : "X6",
"fuel" : ""
}
This should return all cars that are mbw x6 but do not return anything because to this 'fuel'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `filled` instead of `has` if you want to check if a value is present on the request and is not empty.

```
......

if ($request->filled('fuel')) {
    $car = $car->where('fuel', $request->input('fuel'))->with('images');
}

......
```

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests - Section: Determining If An Input Value Is Present